# Plotting a bar graph in expense tracker app

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I want a bar graph of date as x-axis and amount as y-axis. The date is as date list that can have duplicate values but is guarranted to have same len as that of amount list. for eg-date=[2014-1-4,2014-1-4,2014-1-4,2014-1-5] and amount is [100,5000,1000,2000]. The bar graph that I have created is showing duplicate dates as one and other dates as one. Can anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can feed ax.bar a list of [0, 1, 2... n].
And to submit your identical  `labels` = values in [xticks](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

date = ['2014-1-4','2014-1-4','2014-1-4','2014-1-5']

ind = range(len(date))

ax.bar(ind, [100,5000,1000,2000])

plt.xticks(ticks=ind, labels=date)
plt.show()
```